# Error in graph when trying to calculate lead % change month-to-month

Tags: reporting, custom-reports, charts, percent

I am trying to calculate the month-to-month lead % change for my company. I have the created month as a grouped column and I used the following formula to calculate the % change:

```
(RowCount - PREVGROUPVAL(RowCount, CREATED_MONTH)) /  PREVGROUPVAL(RowCount, CREATED_MONTH)
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

I'd like to sort the created month timeline in descending order, so that January 2024 is the first month on the x-axis. I tried sorting the created month in descending order and I get the following graph which is incorrect:

[image]

I rearranged the formula to this to see if it would make a difference:

```
 (PREVGROUPVAL(RowCount, CREATED_MONTH) - RowCount) /  RowCount
```

However, January 2024 is missing from the graph and the values for each month are incorrect:

[image]

I assume this is because I have using PREVGROUPVALUE and there is no data from Feb 2024. Is there a way for me to calculate the percentage change while I include the current month and set the PREVGROUPVALUE to be the previous month when the created month is in descending order?